# Delete broken link

Tags: powershell, hyperlink

I need to delete all the content of a folder which may include broken links among others. The folder path is provided by a variable. Problem is that `PowerShell` fails to remove the broken links.

```
$folderPath = "C:\folder\"
```

Attempt 1:

```
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path $folderPath
```

Fails with error:

```
Remove-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\folder\brokenLink'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path $folderPath
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\folder\brokenLink:String) [Remove-Item], DirectoryNot 
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Attempt 2:

```
Start-Job { cmd /c rmdir $folderPath }
```

Fails because `$folderPath` gets passed as is instead of its value:

```
Start-Job { cmd /c rmdir $folderPath } | select command

Command                                                                                             
-------                                                                                             
 cmd /c rmdir $folderPath
```

Any suggestion besides using the `.NET` framework?

**EDIT**
By broken link I'm referring to a folder which points to a previously mounted partition, that doesn't exist anymore. The folder is still available but when attempting to navigate into it this error occurs because the destination doesn't exist anymore:
Error:

> C:\folder\brokenLink refers to a location that is unavailable. It
>   could be on a hard drive on this computer, or on a network. Check to
>   make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or that you are
>   connected to the Internet or your network, and then try again. If it
>   still cannot be located, the information might have been moved to a
>   different location.

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by "broken link?" Do you have a folder full of shortcut files, or what?

Comment: @TrevorSullivan I've edited the question with my explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
$folderPath = "C:\folderContaingBrokenSymlinks\";
$items = ls $folderPath -Recurse -ea 0;
foreach($item in $items){
    if($item.Attributes.ToString().contains("ReparsePoint")){
        cmd /c rmdir $item.PSPath.replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::","");
    }
    else{
        rm -Force -Recurse $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit instead of just pasting the snippet?