# Delete user folder even with all contents, Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-7, scripting

I know this sort of question has been asked many times, but never does anyone highlight the issue i am facing.

I have a script that will look at user profiles and mark ones that are over X amount of days as ones to delete, then remove them. Remove-Item, with -Force and -Recurse make it remove all folders/files apart from the standard NTFS junction points for all users. For these sort of folders it gets access denied. I have even tried taking ownership of user folders first - still it happens. These folders on W7 being like:

```
C:\Users\<NAME>\My Documents
C:\Users\<NAME>\Start Menu
```

No matter how i make the script it cannot delete the top level user folder. With the same account, same PC - if i just use windows explorer to right click and delete, the folder will be removed along with the sub-folders.

For the record these are the methods i have tried:

```
Remove-Item (with -force -recurse)
[io.directory]::delete()
$variablename.delete()
```

I could post the script but it is kind of irrelevant, as the bulk of it works its just these junction points.

I suppose this is my question - How do i invoke the same delete command Windows Explorer is using from within PowerShell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer, it shows you how to remove symlinks and you can incorporate that into your code: : [Delete broken link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803927/delete-broken-link/21827024#21827024)

Post errors if it doesn't work.

Comment: Error is just access denied, if i use:

    [io.directory]::delete()
    $variablename.delete()

I get a warning showing the destination directory is not empty :(

I shall look into your link and see if it helps, thanks.

Comment: Just tried what you suggested and it doesn't work - copied and pasted into a blank doc. Only error i get is that "Cannot find D:\Documents because it does not exist." I believe this is on the RM part. No other output and no files changed. This was with the script pointing directly at a user folder that is to be removed (C:\Users\Test9444), all that is left are the My Documents, My Videos, Start Menu, SendTo etc etc hidden system folders. Any other ideas? Really becoming annoying haha.

Comment: PowerShell 4.0 too, not mentioned that.

Comment: Adding -Force to that script fixed it. Me being stupid forgot I'd need it for the hidden folders. Think it worked :D will test and then mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me this has to do with the read-attribute on folders set. If I create a junction, I have the habit of immediately changing the icon for it as shown in Explorer. This will set the readonly attribute of the junction which you can't change with explorer, but I can change it with the attrib command :

```
attrib -r /d /s Junk
```

where Junk is a symbolic link to a folder. After that, I can remove the folder with the 'rm'-command